# Run a window containing graphical session of another user

Tags: xorg, users

Is it possible to run — from my graphical session — a window witch contain the graphical session of another user, assuming I am the administrator and I have root privileges?

If yes, how can I do it?

I can’t just open the user’s account from the *DM because I only have access from SSH and X2Go. And, for security reasons, I can’t allow this users to access trough SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the program `xhost` is what are you looking for.

Because of bad english I can not more explain.